# Javascript Event Listener at Interval

Tags: javascript, intervals, event-listener

I'm listening for motion data on devices, using the ondevicemotion API. For example:

```
window.ondevicemotion = function(event) {
    // do something with the event
}
```

I want to run this function when I call it; however, because it is based on an event, it triggers when the event does (which, depending on the device, can be often).

How can I adjust the function so it only listens for the event when I call it, rather than continuously?

Comment: This makes no sense. You either call the function, or an event calls the function. You can't do *both*. If you want to turn event handling on and off, you just need to clear the callback when you want to stop listening.

Comment: Could you add detail to clarify @meagar's question: What do you want to happen when you call the function? Some options: (1) Something always happens; then you don't need an event, just declare a function. (2) something happens if a `devicemotion` happened in the intermeaning calls. (3) I want to be able to have a function/flag that indicates when to start responding to devicemotion and when to stop. (4) I want to respond to devicemotion but ignore it if it happens too frequnetly. etc

Comment: Thanks for the questions. It is closest to 4 -- devicemotion is too frequent, and I only want to check it occasionally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add and remove the event listener as desired:

```
function processMotion(e) {
   // your code here to process devicemotion events
}

function addMotionListener() {
    window.addEventListener("devicemotion", processMotion);
}

function removeMotionLisener() {
    window.removeEventListener("devicemotion", processMotion);
}
```

So, just call `addMotionListener()` when you want to start listening to motion.  Then call `removeMotionListener()` when you want to stop listening to motion.

---

You can't really call `processMotion()` yourself because you need the system to create the system event with all the motion data in it.  Instead, you register the event handler and the system calls you when there's data to be shared.

Comment: Thanks! What if I wanted to do it at set interval? Would I have to add and remove it every time?

Comment: @NiharMadhavan - I don't quite understand what you're asking.  If you don't want the event handler to carry out it's work when the event occurs, you either need to remove the listener or set some sort of flag that the code checks and just does nothing if that flag is set.  If you were toggling this activity a lot, I'd probably just use a flag myself rather than constantly adding/removing the event handler - but you can go either way.